# Login/Logout Session not fully working. JSP

Tags: html, mysql, jsp, jstl

What I want to do is make it that JSP should check if the user is logged in or not. So far my code only checks if the user has visited the website.

So even if the user has not logged in but has already visited the page JSP will think the user is logged in. Code from Homepage:

```
<div style="position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; width: 1000px; text-align:right;">
<% if( session.isNew() ){%>
    <a href="loginpage.jsp">Login<</a>
<%} else { %>
    <a href="logout.jsp">Logout</a>
<% } %>

</div>
```

My code from the actual login page:

```
<!This part is for Username>    
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function AllowAlphabet(){
if (!userform.username.value.match(/^[0123456789]+$/) &&       userform.username.value !="")
{
userform.username.value="";
userform.username.focus();
alert("Please enter only numerials for the Customer number.");
}
}
</script>



<%
if ( session.isNew() )
{out.println("<h3>Welcome new user</h3>" );}
else
{
session.invalidate();
%>
<jsp:forward page="customerlogin.jsp" />
<%
}
%>

<%
if ( request.getParameter("username" ) == null ) 
{out.println("<h3>Please login:</h3>" );}
else
{
pageContext.setAttribute("customerNumberString",request.getParameter( "username" ) );
pageContext.setAttribute("customerPasswordString",request.getParameter( "password" ) );%>

<sql:query var="result">
select * from Customer where
customer_number =
"${customerNumberString}" and
passwd =
MD5(
"${customerPasswordString}" );
</sql:query>
<c:set var = "numResults"
scope = "page"
value = "${result.rowCount}"/>
<%

Object o =
pageContext.getAttribute("numResults" );
Integer obj = new Integer( 1 );
int i = obj.intValue();
if ( pageContext.getAttribute("numResults" ).equals( obj ) )
{
String usernameID = new String( "username" );
String usernameVAL =
new String( request.getParameter("username" ) );
session.setAttribute(usernameID, usernameVAL );
%>
<jsp:forward page="redirectpage.jsp" /> <%
}
else
{out.println("again " );}
}
%>


<form action="customerlogin.jsp"
      name="userform"
      onsubmit="return AllowAlphabet()"
      method="POST">
Customer Number:
<input type="text" name="username" onkeyup="AllowAlphabet()">
<script type="text/javascript">document.onload = ctck();</script>
<br />
Password:
<input type="password" name="password" />
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should consider using Java EE security, then server will take care of protecting your pages, and you will be able to access logged userID via `request.getRemoteUser()`.

If you prefer your home grown security, then you should test, if the user is logged in based on attribute stored in the session, in your case it will probably be `session.getAttribute(usernameID)` and remember to invalidate session on logout.

Answer (score 0):

Its very confusing but I suggest you to do not invalidate session based on session.isNew (use session.isNew only to identify new browser session or first time visit) but, put some variable in session on successful login and write the code based on this session variable.

Hope it helps.